# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, mysqlnd

Since i've moved a site of mine to a new vServer, I always get this error message

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
```

These lines of code are working fine

```
$mysql = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database);
$partys = NULL;
$res_partys = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM party ORDER BY begin");
while($row_partys = $res_partys->fetch_array()) {
    $partys[] = $row_partys;
}
$count_reg = $mysql->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM guestlist WHERE partyid = ?");
$count_reg->bind_param('i', $party['partyid']);
$count_reg->execute();
```

but `$count_res = $count_reg->get_result();` fails. Mysqli support is enabled.

Accorind to some internet sources I need the PHP MySQL native drivers, but I've only got php5-mysql installed on my Debian 7 machine, as installing php5-mysqlnd via `apt-get install php5-mysqlnd` would automatically remove Froxlor, which is my server management panel.

Are there other ways to install mysqlnd except downloading it via `apt-get download php5-mysqlnd` and installing it using dpkg, as this would throw errors on each following apt-get call due to unmet requirements, and compiling PHP including mysqlnd from source?

Comment: which version of PHP are you on? get_result() was added in 5.3.0

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.4.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed installing `php5-mysqlnd` without removing Froxlor.

Froxlor has an dependecy on `php5-mysql`, which is removed by installing `php5-mysqlnd`, but is also compatible to mysqlnd.

So I had to download the package via `apt-get download php5-mysqlnd` and install it using `dpkg -i --ignore-depends=froxlor php5-mysqlnd_5.4.4-14+deb7u7_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 0):

Your server doesnot have mysql native drivers (mysqlnd).

Install this extension in your server to use get result function.

Comment: That's just what I've already written in my question. My problem is that installing mysqlnd via `apt-get install php5-mysqlnd` would remove Froxlor, my server management panel