# Trying to build PHP with MySQL Native Drivers

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mysqli, mysqlnd

I am currently trying to build PHP 5.3.28 with Mysql native Drivers.

This is what my configure script looks like:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php53 \
--with-config-file-path=/etc/php53 \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php53/php.d \
--enable-fpm \
--with-fpm-user=apache \
--with-fpm-group=apache \
--with-libdir=lib64 \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--enable-mbstring \
--disable-debug \
--disable-rpath \
--with-bz2 \
--with-curl \
--with-gettext \
--with-iconv \
--with-openssl \
--with-gd \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-pcre-regex \
--with-zlib
```

However, whenn i set "--with-mysql=mysqlnd \" I get the following error.

```
ext/mysqli/mysqli_warning.c:295: undefined reference to `mysql_warning_count'
```

I am also still getting the error

```
Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
```

Even though, my PHP Info says that mysql and mysqlnd are installed. Does anybody hav e aclue what I am missing here? I am not very good with compiling my own PHP Version, but I need to do it since I am running multiple PHP Versions on my Server.

Comment: The weird thing is, that it throws this error only when i have --with-mysql=mysqlnd but actually throws it inside the mysqli library...

Comment: Have you checked if php5-mysqlnd is installed?  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223268/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result)

Comment: Since I am not using the PHP installation from the Ubuntu Repository, it won't really matter. I wonder if I need any other prerequired stuff to build the mysql extension with native drivers.

Comment: try to run `make clean` before build